If $A$ and $B$ are disjoint subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ ,$B$ is Lebesgue measurable then $|A\cup B|=|A|+|B|$.
$|·|$ is outer measure.
I only need to prove $|A\cup B|\geq|A|+|B|$.
I've proved that if $B$ is open, then $|A\cup B|=|A|+|B|$.
Since $B$ is Lebesuge measurable, there exists an open set $O\supset B$ such that $|O-B|<\epsilon$.
My initial idea was to approximate $B$ with $O$,then
$$|A\cup B|\geq |A\cup O|-\epsilon=|A|+|O|-\epsilon$$
But I've found that $O$ doesn't have to be disjoint with $A$. So it doesn't feel like it's gonna work. In summary, if I want to find an open set to cover $B$, there is no guarantee that this open set will not intersect $A$. I'm running out of other ideas, can anyone help me? Thanks in advance!

Sure would be handy if $A$ and $B$ were disjoint.  Maybe write as three sets: $C = A \cap B$, $A' = A \smallsetminus C$, and $B' = B \smallsetminus C$.  You know the measure of $C \cup B'$ and $A' \cup C \subset A$...

Proof 1: Suppose $A$ and $B$ are disjoint subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ and $B$ is Lebesgue measurable. Since $B$ is Lebesgue measurable, we have, for any subset $E$ of $\mathbb{R}$,
$$
|E| = |E \cap B| + |E \cap B^c|
$$
Take $E = A \cup B$. Since $A$ and $B$ are disjoint, we have $E \cap B =B$ and $E \cap B^c = A$. So we have
$$
|A \cup B| = |B| + |A|
$$
that is $|A\cup B|=|A|+|B|$.
$\square$
Since the OP would like a proof using GTM282 by Sheldon Axler (pages 50,51,52). Here it is
Proof 2: We know that

(2.66 page 50) If $A$ and $B$ are disjoint subset of $\Bbb R$ and $B$ is a Borel set, then $|A \cup B | = |A| + |B|$.


(2.70 page 52) Definition: A set $A \subseteq \Bbb R$ is called Lebesgue measurable if there exists a Borel set $B \subseteq A$
such that $|A \setminus B| = 0$.

Now, suppose $A$ and $B$ are disjoint subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ and $B$ is Lebesgue measurable. Then, by the definition of Lebesgue measurable set, there is a Borel set $C \subseteq B$ such that $|B \setminus C| = 0$.
Using the fact the $B \setminus C$ and $C$ are disjoint and $C$ is a Borel set, we can apply 2.66 and we have
$$
|B| = |(B \setminus C) \cup C| = |B \setminus C| +|C| =|C|
$$
Now, since $C \subseteq B$, we have that $A$ and $C$ are also disjoint. Using the monotonicity of outer measure, the result 2.66 again and the fact that $|B| =|C|$, we have
$$
|A \cup B| \geqslant |A \cup C| = |A| +|C| = |A|+|B|
$$
So $|A \cup B| \geqslant |A|+|B|$. It follows immediately that
$$
|A \cup B| = |A|+|B|
$$
$\square$

I don't know the first display, could you give me some references?

@Ychen  , It is the Carathéodory's criterion. In some books and sites it is used as the definition of "Lebesgue measurable set".  For quick references:


See Carathéodory's criterion in the Definition section in the link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_measure


See link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_criterion


See link https://heil.math.gatech.edu/6337/spring11/section1.5.pdf



Thanks,  my book's definition of a Lebesgue measurable set is that there exists a Borel set $B\subset A$ such that $|A-B|<\epsilon$. I will learn about Carathéodory's criterion in a later chapter. If you have another idea that would be great, maybe I'll have to put that aside for a while. Thank you very much for your answer. @Ramiro

@Ychen , What are the exact definitions you have of the Lebesgue outer measure and Lebesgue measurable set?

The textbook I use is GTM282 by Sheldon Axler. In page 51&52, Lebesgue measure is the measure on $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B} )$, where $,\mathcal{B}$ is the $\sigma$-algebra of Borel
subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, that assigns to each Borel set its outer measure. A set $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ is called Lebesgue measurable if there exists a Borel set $B\subset A$
such that $|A \ B| = 0$.

@Ychen , I have added a second proof in my answer. It based on GTM282 by Sheldon Axler, Chapter 2.  I think it is the solution you are looking for.
